# WordPress: "Only variables should be passed by reference" Error

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

This is a part of the WordPress bbPress importer to import vBulletin to WordPress. However, this error repeats on EVERY Single Topic Import and I have no idea what to use for syntax in it's place.

**Code**

```
else {
    $name = @$token[BBCODE_STACK_TAG]['_name'];
    $rule = @$this->tag_rules[$name];
    $end_tag = @$rule['end_tag'];
    if (!isset($rule['end_tag'])) $end_tag = BBCODE_REQUIRED;
    else $end_tag = $rule['end_tag'];
    array_pop($this->start_tags[$name]);
    if ($end_tag == BBCODE_PROHIBIT) {
        $output[] = Array(
            BBCODE_STACK_TOKEN => BBCODE_TEXT,
            BBCODE_STACK_TAG => false,
            BBCODE_STACK_TEXT => $token[BBCODE_STACK_TEXT],
            BBCODE_STACK_CLASS => $this->current_class,
        );
    }
    else {
        if ($end_tag == BBCODE_REQUIRED)
        @$this->lost_start_tags[$name] += 1;
        $end = $this->Internal_CleanupWSByIteratingPointer(@$rule['before_endtag'], 0, $output);
        $this->Internal_CleanupWSByPoppingStack(@$rule['after_tag'], $output);
        $tag_body = $this->Internal_CollectTextReverse($output, count($output)-1, $end);
        $this->Internal_CleanupWSByPoppingStack(@$rule['before_tag'], $this->stack);
        $this->Internal_UpdateParamsForMissingEndTag(@$token[BBCODE_STACK_TAG]); // Line 1823
        $tag_output = $this->DoTag(BBCODE_OUTPUT, $name,
        @$token[BBCODE_STACK_TAG]['_default'], @$token[BBCODE_STACK_TAG], $tag_body);
        $output = Array(Array(
            BBCODE_STACK_TOKEN => BBCODE_TEXT,
            BBCODE_STACK_TAG => false,
            BBCODE_STACK_TEXT => $tag_output,
            BBCODE_STACK_CLASS => $this->current_class
        ));
    }
```

**Error**

> PHP Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in `/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/admin/parser.php on line 1823`

Comment: Which line is 1823? Please be clear when you ask a question.

Comment: @KoenHollander I did, it's marked //line 1823
`$this->Internal_UpdateParamsForMissingEndTag(@$token[BBCODE_STACK_TAG]); // Line 1823`

I just left the code around it for clarity on how it's being used.